# MYSQL Results from 2 tables (JOIN not working out)

Tags: mysql

Running into a situation where I am trying to get data from 2 tables but am not getting the right results using JOIN.

**Sample query:** `SELECT a.data_a, b.data_b  FROM Table_A JOIN Table_B USING (ref) WHERE ref = 10;`.

```
Table_A
---------------------
| id | data_a | ref |
---------------------
| 1  | 123    | 10  |
---------------------

Table_B
---------------------
| id | data_b | ref |
---------------------
| 1  | 456    | 10  |
| 2  | 789    | 10  |
---------------------
```

What I am getting back is...

```
-------------------
| data_a | data_b |
-------------------
| 123    | 456    |
| 123    | 789    |
-------------------
```

What I want is...

```
-------------------
| data_a | data_b |
-------------------
| 123    |        |
|        | 456    |
|        | 789    |
-------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `join` for this scenario, use `union` instead.

```
select distinct a.data_a as data_a, '' as data_b from tableA where ref = 10
union all
select distinct '', b.data_b from tableB where ref = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `JOIN`, you should use `UNION` to get the data on separate rows.

```
SELECT data_a, "" AS data_b
FROM Table_A
WHERE ref = 10
UNION
SELECT "" AS data_a, data_b
FROM Table_B
WHERE ref = 10
```